# The command line is too long Standard error from the DataNucleus tool

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven, datanucleus

I am getting this error

```
The command line is too long.

mvn install

Standard error from the DataNucleus tool  org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer 

The command line is too long.
```

Comment: Does http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,5590 help you?

Answer (score 14):

If you is using datanucleus-maven-plugin in windows simply set **fork** property as **false** in configuration of plugin as follow:

```
 <plugins>
  ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-release</version>
        <configuration>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <fork>false</fork>   <!-- Solve windows line too long error -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
```

See the [datanucleus enhancer page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/enhancer.html) for more datails.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/troubleshooting.html.
and here: http://code.google.com/p/vosao/issues/detail?id=47.

==============QUOTE==============

Problem

CreateProcess error=87 when running DataNucleus tools under Microsoft Windows OS.

Windows has a command line length limitation, between 8K and 64K characters depending
on the Windows version, that may be triggered when running tools such as the Enhancer
or the SchemaTool with too many arguments.

Solution

When running such tools from Maven or Ant, disable the fork mechanism by setting the
option fork="false". 
==============END==============

pom.xml file needs to be adjusted as follows:

==============WAS==============

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    ....
    <configuration>
        <mappingIncludes>**/*.class</mappingIncludes>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
        <api>JDO</api>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

==============END WAS==============

==============SHOULD BE==============

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    ....
    <configuration>
        <fork>false</fork>
        <mappingIncludes>org/vosao/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
        <api>JDO</api>
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

==============SHOULD BE==============

My suggested change to pom.xml also specifies limiting scope of Enhancer work area.